# cannot import name 'RESTClient' from 'polygon'

Tags: python, import, polygon, rest-client

While i trying to conect polygon API using python:

```
from polygon import RESTClient
```

and it would result:

```
cannot import name 'RESTClient' from 'polygon'
```

But I dont know why it isn't work. It  originaly no error last week.

enter:

```
from polygon import RESTClient
```

result:

```
cannot import name 'RESTClient' from 'polygon'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, it was because I installed the package `polygon`, when I needed to install `polygon-api-client`.

Installing the correct package fixed it.